# Latitude Longitude Coordinates to State Code in R

Tags: r, latitude-longitude, google-geocoder

Is there a fast way to convert latitude and longitude coordinates to State codes in R? I've been using the zipcode package as a look up table but it's too slow when I'm querying lots of lat/long values

If not in R is there any way to do this using google geocoder or any other type of fast querying service?

Thanks!

Comment: see also my answer here, using `ggmap::revgeocode` : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46150851/how-to-get-california-county-location-from-latitude-and-longitude-information/46151310#46151310

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Here are two options, one using **sf** and one using **sp** package functions. **sf** is the more modern (and, here in 2020, recommended) package for analyzing spatial data, but in case it's still useful, I am leaving my original 2012 answer showing how to do this with **sp**-related functions.

---

### Method 1 (using sf):

```r
library(sf)
library(spData)

## pointsDF: A data.frame whose first column contains longitudes and
##           whose second column contains latitudes.
##
## states:   An sf MULTIPOLYGON object with 50 states plus DC.
##
## name_col: Name of a column in `states` that supplies the states'
##           names.
lonlat_to_state <- function(pointsDF,
                            states = spData::us_states,
                            name_col = "NAME") {
    ## Convert points data.frame to an sf POINTS object
    pts <- st_as_sf(pointsDF, coords = 1:2, crs = 4326)

    ## Transform spatial data to some planar coordinate system
    ## (e.g. Web Mercator) as required for geometric operations
    states <- st_transform(states, crs = 3857)
    pts <- st_transform(pts, crs = 3857)

    ## Find names of state (if any) intersected by each point
    state_names <- states[[name_col]]
    ii <- as.integer(st_intersects(pts, states))
    state_names[ii]
}

## Test the function with points in Wisconsin, Oregon, and France
testPoints <- data.frame(x = c(-90, -120, 0), y = c(44, 44, 44))
lonlat_to_state(testPoints)
## [1] "Wisconsin" "Oregon"    NA
```

If you need higher resolution state boundaries, read in your own vector data as an `sf` object using `sf::st_read()` or by some other means. One nice option is to install the **rnaturalearth** package and use it to load a state vector layer from **rnaturalearthhires**. Then use the `lonlat_to_state()` function we just defined as shown here:

```r
library(rnaturalearth)
us_states_ne <- ne_states(country = "United States of America",
                          returnclass = "sf")
lonlat_to_state(testPoints, states = us_states_ne, name_col = "name")
## [1] "Wisconsin" "Oregon"    NA
```

For very accurate results, you can download a geopackage containing [GADM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GADM)-maintained administrative borders for the United States from [this page](https://gadm.org/download_country_v3.html). Then, load the state boundary data and use them like this:

```r
USA_gadm <- st_read(dsn = "gadm36_USA.gpkg", layer = "gadm36_USA_1")
lonlat_to_state(testPoints, states = USA_gadm, name_col = "NAME_1")
## [1] "Wisconsin" "Oregon"    NA
```

---

### Method 2 (using sp):

Here is a function that takes a data.frame of lat-longs within the lower 48 states, and for each point, returns the state in which it is located.

Most of the function simply prepares the `SpatialPoints` and `SpatialPolygons` objects needed by the `over()` function in the `sp` package, which does the real heavy lifting of calculating the 'intersection' of points and polygons:

```r
library(sp)
library(maps)
library(maptools)

# The single argument to this function, pointsDF, is a data.frame in which:
#   - column 1 contains the longitude in degrees (negative in the US)
#   - column 2 contains the latitude in degrees

lonlat_to_state_sp <- function(pointsDF) {
    # Prepare SpatialPolygons object with one SpatialPolygon
    # per state (plus DC, minus HI & AK)
    states <- map('state', fill=TRUE, col="transparent", plot=FALSE)
    IDs <- sapply(strsplit(states$names, ":"), function(x) x[1])
    states_sp <- map2SpatialPolygons(states, IDs=IDs,
                     proj4string=CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))

    # Convert pointsDF to a SpatialPoints object 
    pointsSP <- SpatialPoints(pointsDF, 
                    proj4string=CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))

    # Use 'over' to get _indices_ of the Polygons object containing each point 
        indices <- over(pointsSP, states_sp)

    # Return the state names of the Polygons object containing each point
    stateNames <- sapply(states_sp@polygons, function(x) x@ID)
    stateNames[indices]
}

# Test the function using points in Wisconsin and Oregon.
testPoints <- data.frame(x = c(-90, -120), y = c(44, 44))

lonlat_to_state_sp(testPoints)
[1] "wisconsin" "oregon" # IT WORKS
```

Comment: I had to change wgs84 to WGS84 to get this example to work.

Comment: @lever Thanks for pointing that out. Wonder when (and where) that was changed. In any case, I've now edited to fix it.

Comment: Is there a quick edit to get this to go from lat/lon to Zip Codes instead of states?

Comment: @AgustínIndaco Not quick, since in my code, the polygon layer of states is provided by the **maps** package, and it has no corresponding layer of zip code boundaries. If you find such a layer, you could of course adapt my code to work with it. Alternatively, you may want to look into "reverse geocoding" as, e.g., [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37117595/980833).

Comment: I've found this answer produces results that lack adequate precision for some applications. For example, `38.83226,-76.98946` is coded as Maryland, not the District of Columbia. And `34.97982,-85.42203` is coded as Tennessee, not Georgia. If you're working with 15,000 points, as I am, this method is going to produce a lot of incorrect results (about 900 in the data set I'm working with, I'd estimate). I'm not sure what a better solution would be, however.

Comment: This also works well for county by changing "state" to "county".

Comment: @LaissezPasser Thanks for mentioning that. For much more accurate results, you can use the code I just now posted under **Method 1** and the [GADM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GADM)-maintained dataset mentioned near the bottom of that section.

Answer (score 13):

You can do it in a few lines of R.

```
library(sp)
library(rgdal)
#lat and long
Lat <- 57.25
Lon <- -9.41
#make a data frame
coords <- as.data.frame(cbind(Lon,Lat))
#and into Spatial
points <- SpatialPoints(coords)
#SpatialPolygonDataFrame - I'm using a shapefile of UK counties
counties <- readOGR(".", "uk_counties")
#assume same proj as shapefile!
proj4string(points) <- proj4string(counties)
#get county polygon point is in
result <- as.character(over(points, counties)$County_Name)
```

Answer (score 3):

See `?over` in the sp package.

You'll need to have the state boundaries as a *SpatialPolygonsDataFrame*.

Answer (score 0):

Example data (polygons and points)

```
library(raster)
pols <- shapefile(system.file("external/lux.shp", package="raster"))
xy <- coordinates(p)
```

Use raster::extract

```
extract(p, xy)

#   point.ID poly.ID ID_1       NAME_1 ID_2           NAME_2 AREA
#1         1       1    1     Diekirch    1         Clervaux  312
#2         2       2    1     Diekirch    2         Diekirch  218
#3         3       3    1     Diekirch    3          Redange  259
#4         4       4    1     Diekirch    4          Vianden   76
#5         5       5    1     Diekirch    5            Wiltz  263
#6         6       6    2 Grevenmacher    6       Echternach  188
#7         7       7    2 Grevenmacher    7           Remich  129
#8         8       8    2 Grevenmacher   12     Grevenmacher  210
#9         9       9    3   Luxembourg    8         Capellen  185
#10       10      10    3   Luxembourg    9 Esch-sur-Alzette  251
#11       11      11    3   Luxembourg   10       Luxembourg  237
#12       12      12    3   Luxembourg   11           Mersch  233
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick and easy way to convert latitude and longitude to U.S. state and U.S. state abbreviation.

```r
# library(remotes)
# install_github("JVAdams/jvamisc") # if you are installing this for the first time you will need to load the remotes package
library(jvamisc)
library(stringr)
#> Warning: package 'stringr' was built under R version 4.2.3

# Example Data
data <- data.frame(
  longitude = c(-74.28000,-80.62036,-77.43923),
  latitude = c(40.99194,33.82849,37.54588))

# Use function latlong2 from library(jvamisc) to convert lat and long points to state
data$state <- latlong2(data, to = 'state')

# Use function str_to_title form library(stringr) to make the first letter of each state uppercase
data$state <- str_to_title(data$state)

# Convert state name to state abbreviation
data$state_abb <- state.abb[match(data$state, state.name)]

data
#>   longitude latitude          state state_abb
#> 1 -74.28000 40.99194     New Jersey        NJ
#> 2 -80.62036 33.82849 South Carolina        SC
#> 3 -77.43923 37.54588       Virginia        VA
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score -1):

It's very straightforward using [`sf`](https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/):

```
library(maps)
library(sf)

## Get the states map, turn into sf object
US <- st_as_sf(map("state", plot = FALSE, fill = TRUE))

## Test the function using points in Wisconsin and Oregon
testPoints <- data.frame(x = c(-90, -120), y = c(44, 44))

# Make it a spatial dataframe, using the same coordinate system as the US spatial dataframe
testPoints <- st_as_sf(testPoints, coords = c("x", "y"), crs = st_crs(US))

#.. and perform a spatial join!
st_join(testPoints, US)


         ID        geometry
1 wisconsin  POINT (-90 44)
2    oregon POINT (-120 44)
```