# Geolocation function input to dataframe

Tags: r, function, geolocation

I am having trouble taking the function from this question ([R convert zipcode or lat/long to county](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13316185/r-convert-zipcode-or-lat-long-to-county)) to add county and state names to my file:

```
structure(df)
  Recovery.Date SPECIES_ID LAT_FLOAT LON_FLOAT   ZIP
9/23/2009       1720  42.91667 -71.41667  3051
10/8/2006       1440     42.75 -72.41667  3451
10/17/2011       1330     39.25 -74.91667  8316
2/4/2012       1690     39.25 -75.91667 21050
12/31/2009       1320     38.25    -75.25 21837
```

I want to take the lat_float and long_float values into the function and then add county and state (separately or together) as a new column in df. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you know by any chance what is the projection system in use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1 - Create Data.frame pointsDF

```
pointsDF <- subset(df, select=c("LON_FLOAT", "LAT_FLOAT"))
```

Step 2 - Make sure you have the right projection/datum

Step 3 - Follow the accepted answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13316185/r-convert-zipcode-or-lat-long-to-county).

Step 4 - Merge or Join your two datasets with Lon== & LAT==  conditions or you combine lon+lat in one variable on both sides and use it has a key.