# Zip Codes from Lat/Lon (batch query)

Tags: r, latitude-longitude, zipcode

I have a data.frame with 1500 latitude/longitude entries. I need to map these coordinates to their zip codes. Is there a way to do this besides entering them in one at a time to a geonames -type api? I would like a package in `R` that takes in a lat-lon combo and produces a zip code for every row of my data.frame.

Comment: Check this also : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13316185/r-convert-zipcode-or-lat-long-to-county

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the Open Streetmap API, you could try

```
library(RCurl)
library(RJSONIO)

latlon2zip <- function(lat, lon) {
    url <- sprintf("http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=json&lat=%f&lon=%f&zoom=18&addressdetails=1", lat, lon)
    res <- fromJSON(url)
    return(res[["address"]][["postcode"]])
}

latlon2zip(lat=52.5487429714954, lon=-1.81602098644987)
```

In order to use the `latlon2zip` function in `transform`, use `Vectorize`.