# Using R to spatial join a data frame of lat/long points to a polygon shapefil

Tags: r, geospatial, shapefile, rgdal, r-maptools

I'm hoping to write an R program that reads in a data frame of lat/long points and a shapefile of 13 polygons, and then identifies which polygon each lat/long point is located within. Is there an R package that enables me to do this type of spatial join? I've been using rgdal to read the polygon shapefile, but I don't see an option for conducting a spatial join with the lat/long columns in my dataframe. Thanks!

Comment: as easy as converting your lat/long dataframe to a `SpatialPointsDataFrame` and then use the function `over` from `library(sp)`

Comment: This may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13316185/r-convert-zipcode-or-lat-long-to-county/20131701#20131701

Comment: Worked great. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

G. Cocca's solution worked great after some minor modifications.

Ultimately, the solution required four steps using `R`'s `library(sp)` and `library(EcoSpatial)`:

1. Convert lat/long point dataframe to a `SpatialPointsDataFrame` using `sp`.
2. Use `sp`'s `proj4string` function to reproject the `SpatialPointsDataFrame` so that it uses the same projection as my polygon shapefile.
3. Use `EcoSpatial`'s `points.in.poly` function to spatially join the two datasets. This is the key step, as it creates a new `SpatialPointsDataframe` that affixes relevant polgyon data to each xy point.
4. Use `as.data.frame` to coerce the `SpatialPointsDataframe` back into a regular `R` `data.frame`.

Thanks again for the help!