# how can i extract California county locations from given latitude and longitude information

Tags: r, geolocation, mapping, geocoding

I have the following dataset for California housing data:

```
head(calif_cluster,15)
   MedianHouseValue MedianIncome MedianHouseAge TotalRooms TotalBedrooms Population
1            190300      4.20510             16    2697.00        490.00       1462
2            150800      2.54810             33    2821.00        652.00       1206
3            252600      6.08290             17    6213.20       1276.05       3288
4            269700      4.03680             52     919.00        213.00        413
5             91200      1.63680             28    3072.00        790.00       1375
6             66200      2.18980             30     744.00        156.00        410
7            148800      2.63640             39     620.95        136.00        348
8            384800      4.46150             20    2270.00        498.00       1070
9            153200      2.75000             22    1931.00        445.00       1009
10            66200      1.60057             36     973.00        219.00        613
11           461500      3.78130             43    3070.00        668.00       1240
12           144600      2.85000             22    5175.00       1213.00       2804
13           143700      5.09410              8    6213.20       1276.05       3288
14           195500      5.30620             16    2918.00        444.00       1697
15           268800      2.42110             22     620.95        136.00        348
   Households Latitude Longitude cluster_kmeans gender_dom marital     race edu_level rental
1         515    38.48   -122.47              1          M   other    black jrcollege rented
2         640    38.00   -122.13              1          F   other hispanic doctorate  owned
3        1162    33.88   -117.79              3          M   other    white jrcollege  owned
4         193    37.85   -122.25              1          M  single   others jrcollege  owned
5         705    38.13   -122.26              1          F  single    white doctorate rented
6         165    38.96   -122.21              1          F  single   others jrcollege  owned
7         125    34.01   -118.18              2          M married   others  postgrad  owned
8         521    33.83   -118.38              2          F  single    white  graduate rented
9         407    38.95   -121.04              1          M married   others  postgrad leased
10        187    35.34   -119.01              2          M  single hispanic doctorate  owned
11        646    33.76   -118.12              2          F   other   others  highschl leased
12       1091    37.95   -122.05              3          M   other    white  graduate rented
13       1162    36.87   -119.75              3          M   other   others  postgrad leased
14        444    32.93   -117.13              2          M   other    asian jrcollege  owned
15        125    37.71   -120.98              1          F  single    asian  postgrad leased
```

As i have latitude & longitude information in the datasets, i would like to extract corresponding `county` for the given geo information using R. Also is it possible to getting the capital city(or largest city) for each of the extracted counties .These could make my stratified analysis more insightful;intend to do some clustering/mapping exercise.

Comment: You should have a look on [that website](http://catalog.opendata.city/dataset/california-counties-polygon/resource/6f805645-0836-478d-b168-c1f72d53b4f3). When you got this `geoJson` file, download the `rgdal`package, you will find all what you need : [rgdal documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgdal/rgdal.pdf).

Comment: Follow the "tingenek"'s comment on [that page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751497/latitude-longitude-coordinates-to-state-code-in-r) (4 upvotes, 3rd post including the question) to do what you need.

Comment: Please show what you've tried and where you get stuck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Latitude Longitude Coordinates to State Code in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751497/latitude-longitude-coordinates-to-state-code-in-r)

Comment: how is it off topic ? this is an objective question, and not asking for a book or library recommendation

Comment: @Uwe   The qs may look like it is duplicate but if u see the solution given by `Moody_Mudskipper` which is awesome as compared to the earlier duplicate SO thread answers.; we have now multiple solutions;so posting duplicate qs sometimes is good!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

take a look at `ggmap::revgeocode`

**code**

```
library(ggmap)
revgeocode(c(-122.47,38.48)) # longitude then latitude
# [1] "2233 Sulphur Springs Ave, St Helena, CA 94574, USA"

library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
df12 %<>% rowwise %>% mutate(address = revgeocode(c(Longitude,Latitude))) %>% ungroup        # add full address using google api through ggmap
df12 %<>% separate(address,c("street_address", "city","county","country"),remove=F,sep=",")  # structure all the info you need
```

**result**

```
df12 %>% select(Longitude,Latitude,address,county)
# A tibble: 15 x 4
# Longitude Latitude                                            address    county
# *     <dbl>    <dbl>                                              <chr>     <chr>
#  1   -122.47    38.48 2233 Sulphur Springs Ave, St Helena, CA 94574, USA  CA 94574
#  2   -122.13    38.00    3400-3410 Brookside Dr, Martinez, CA 94553, USA  CA 94553
#  3   -117.79    33.88  19721 Bluefield Plaza, Yorba Linda, CA 92886, USA  CA 92886
#  4   -122.25    37.85             6365 Florio St, Oakland, CA 94618, USA  CA 94618
#  5   -122.26    38.13              119 Mimosa Ct, Vallejo, CA 94589, USA  CA 94589
#  6   -122.21    38.96              Unnamed Road, Arbuckle, CA 95912, USA  CA 95912
#  7   -118.18    34.01    4360-4414 Noakes St, Los Angeles, CA 90023, USA  CA 90023
#  8   -118.38    33.83    903 Serpentine St, Redondo Beach, CA 90277, USA  CA 90277
#  9   -121.04    38.95        14666-14690 Musso Rd, Auburn, CA 95603, USA  CA 95603
# 10   -119.01    35.34           800 Ming Ave, Bakersfield, CA 93307, USA  CA 93307
# 11   -118.12    33.76   6211-6295 E Marina Dr, Long Beach, CA 90803, USA  CA 90803
# 12   -122.05    37.95              1120 Carey Dr, Concord, CA 94520, USA  CA 94520
# 13   -119.75    36.87        1815-1899 E Pryor Dr, Fresno, CA 93720, USA  CA 93720
# 14   -117.13    32.93      9010-9016 Danube Ln, San Diego, CA 92126, USA  CA 92126
# 15   -120.98    37.71       748-1298 Claribel Rd, Modesto, CA 95356, USA  CA 95356
```

**data**

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "MedianHouseValue MedianIncome MedianHouseAge TotalRooms TotalBedrooms Population
    1            190300      4.20510             16    2697.00        490.00       1462
                      2            150800      2.54810             33    2821.00        652.00       1206
                      3            252600      6.08290             17    6213.20       1276.05       3288
                      4            269700      4.03680             52     919.00        213.00        413
                      5             91200      1.63680             28    3072.00        790.00       1375
                      6             66200      2.18980             30     744.00        156.00        410
                      7            148800      2.63640             39     620.95        136.00        348
                      8            384800      4.46150             20    2270.00        498.00       1070
                      9            153200      2.75000             22    1931.00        445.00       1009
                      10            66200      1.60057             36     973.00        219.00        613
                      11           461500      3.78130             43    3070.00        668.00       1240
                      12           144600      2.85000             22    5175.00       1213.00       2804
                      13           143700      5.09410              8    6213.20       1276.05       3288
                      14           195500      5.30620             16    2918.00        444.00       1697
                      15           268800      2.42110             22     620.95        136.00        348",header=T,stringsAsFactors=F)


df2 <- read.table(text = "Households Latitude Longitude cluster_kmeans gender_dom marital     race edu_level rental
                  1         515    38.48   -122.47              1          M   other    black jrcollege rented
                  2         640    38.00   -122.13              1          F   other hispanic doctorate  owned
                  3        1162    33.88   -117.79              3          M   other    white jrcollege  owned
                  4         193    37.85   -122.25              1          M  single   others jrcollege  owned
                  5         705    38.13   -122.26              1          F  single    white doctorate rented
                  6         165    38.96   -122.21              1          F  single   others jrcollege  owned
                  7         125    34.01   -118.18              2          M married   others  postgrad  owned
                  8         521    33.83   -118.38              2          F  single    white  graduate rented
                  9         407    38.95   -121.04              1          M married   others  postgrad leased
                  10        187    35.34   -119.01              2          M  single hispanic doctorate  owned
                  11        646    33.76   -118.12              2          F   other   others  highschl leased
                  12       1091    37.95   -122.05              3          M   other    white  graduate rented
                  13       1162    36.87   -119.75              3          M   other   others  postgrad leased
                  14        444    32.93   -117.13              2          M   other    asian jrcollege  owned
                  15        125    37.71   -120.98              1          F  single    asian  postgrad leased",header=T,stringsAsFactors=F)

df12 <- cbind(df1,df2)
```

I don't think the library offers an option to get the capital or largest city in the county but I think you won't have too much trouble building a lookup table from online info.

Comment: Good example of ggmap::revgeocode, but those are zip codes, not counties.

Comment: Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/20131701/4663008, it looks like revgeocode could pull the county if you ask for administrative_area_level_2