# how to map latitude/longitude to a specific US county?

Tags: python, r, geolocation

I have a dataframe containing U.S. `latitude` and `longitude` coordinates.

I would like to create a variable that shows the respective U.S. county that includes these coordinates.

How can I do that in R/Python?

Thanks!

Comment: The best way is using Google Maps API. But, you should register your app for getting api-key. Here is link https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start Allso `geopy` is good lib for it

Comment: Something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13316185/r-convert-zipcode-or-lat-long-to-county

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R convert zipcode or lat/long to county](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13316185/r-convert-zipcode-or-lat-long-to-county)

Comment: not a duplicate. zip codes can span multiple counties while lat loc does not. my question is more specific

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [geopy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/geopy).

Example from the documentation using Nominatim (Open Street Map):

```
>>> from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
>>> geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="http")
>>> location = geolocator.reverse("52.509669, 13.376294")
>>> print(location.address)
Potsdamer Platz, Mitte, Berlin, 10117, Deutschland, European Union
>>> print((location.latitude, location.longitude))
(52.5094982, 13.3765983)
>>> print(location.raw)
{'place_id': '654513', 'osm_type': 'node', ...}
```

The raw output has a dict key `country`, if one can be found.

Comment: nice! by looking at its GitHub i see the build is failing. what does that mean?