# Adding density to a spatial map in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, gis, geospatial

Objective: Adding density to a map

Tested Packages: ggplot, ggmap, sp, rgdal

Based on the rdgal package, I have a map of a specific state.

```
library(rgdal)
us<-getData('GADM', country='USA', level=2)  
WV <-subset(us, NAME_1=="West Virginia")
plot(WV)
```

I want to plot some prescription data on the map. Based on the geocode() method, specified in the following post:
[R convert zipcode or lat/long to county](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13316185/r-convert-zipcode-or-lat-long-to-county), I converted the county name to a set of latitude and longitude coordinates.

```
library(ggmap)
WV.opioid <- opioid.dat[opioid.dat$State.Name == "West Virginia",]
WV.coordinates <- geocode(as.character(WV.opioid$County.Name))
WV.opioid <- cbind(WV.opioid, WV.coordinates)
WV.opioid <- WV.opioid[which(!is.na(WV.opioid$lat)),]
rownames(WV.opioid) <- NULL
```

I have tried to plot one column of the dataset on the map:

```
 library(ggplot2)
 #opioid data from following link: https://www.datafiles.samhsa.gov/study-series/national-survey-drug-use-and-health-nsduh-nid13517
 opioid.map <- ggplot(WV.opioid, aes(x = lon, y = lat, 
                             fill = cut_number(Diff.Opioid.Prescription.Rates, 
 5))) +
 geom_polygon(color = "gray10", size = 0.2) +
 coord_equal() +
 viridis::scale_fill_viridis(discrete = TRUE) +
 labs(title = "Test",
 fill = NULL) +
 theme_void() +
 theme(legend.position = "bottom",
 panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA, colour = "#cccccc"))
 opioid.map
```

[image]

I am not sure how to fix this plot and would appreciate help. I have also tried to use the rdgal package and add my data to a SpatialPoints object but have not been successful.

Comment: Could you please add the packages you are using to your code?

Comment: Your code is not reproducible. There isn't any package called `rdgal`. Where did `opioid.dat` come from?

Comment: @Tung I have addressed your comments in my post.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what spatial resolution the opioid data is at, but I would recommend finding a shapefile that fits it, rather than using lat/lon county centroids. This type of transformation isn't really correct if you don't correct for the [modifiable areal unit problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modifiable_areal_unit_problem).

If the opioid data is by zip code, there are shapefiles at that resolution in the `tigris` package.

I think the main problem is in this transformation you are doing in the second code chunk. Once you are no longer doing that, it should be fairly simple to plot a chloropleth of the prescription rates.