# Is there a possible way to get from latitude/longitude or address to county subdivision name and FIPS code in R?

Tags: r

I have a data set that I have obtained from the IPEDS data center that has demographic information for all post-secondary education schools in the United States. I am trying to identify each school within a county subdivision (i.e. municipality, borough, township...) so that I can match each school to certain economic indicators for that area. I have multiple data sets ready to merge and begin analysis, however, I need an identifier that I can merge them on. Is this at all possible within R? I have looked at the revgeo function but it's not quite what I'm looking for. 
Much appreciated!

Comment: Have you looked at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13316185/r-convert-zipcode-or-lat-long-to-county

Comment: The `ggmap` package has a geocode function.

Comment: Thank you, the `ggmap` package gave me what I was looking for. I had looked at the thread you provided a couple of days ago and had no luck adapting the code for the county subdivision level.