# How to join data with a weighted sampling?

Tags: r, join, dplyr, sample

I'm looking to do a weighted join between two datasets:

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(1)

test.sample <- data.frame(zip=sample(1:3,50,replace = TRUE))

index.dat <- data.frame(zip=c(1,1,2,3,3,3),
                  fips=c("A1", "A2", "B", "C1", "C2","C3"),
                  prob=c(.75,.25,1,.7,.2,.1))
```

My expected output would be a weighted sample from the index dataset:

```
results1 <- c(rep("A1",14),rep("A2",4),rep("B",19,),rep("C1",9),rep("C2",3),"C3")
```

Ultimately trying to join zip codes that match to multiple fips codes from a probability distribution for the population.

This comment is a good description of what I'm trying to overcome: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13316857/4828653

Here's a potential solution I've come up with but given I have billions of records I need something much more performant.

```
test_function <- function(x) {
index.dat %>% 
filter(zip == x) %>% 
sample_n(size=1,weight=prob) %>% 
select(fips)
}

results2 <- lapply(test.sample$zip, function(x) test_function(x)) %>% 
unlist() %>% 
data.frame(fips = .)

> table(results1)
results1
A1 A2  B C1 C2 C3 
14  4 19  9  3  1 
> table(results2)
results2
A1 A2  B C1 C2 C3 
15  3 19  8  2  3
```

Comment: Please use `set.seed()` when using functions such as `sample()` to ensure reproducibility

Comment: My mistake on the Cs. The fips are assigned probabilities based on population distribution. These are just arbitrary values I set for a simple example.

Comment: The thing that I don't understand is `A1` and `A2` combine have probability 1 which gets 14 + 5 = 19 rows. `B` has probability 1 which gets 20 rows where as C has combined probability 1 as well and they have only 11 rows. How with same probability you get different number of rows ? What is the logic there ?

Comment: I've adjusted the result numbers to seed = 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split `index.dat` according to the `zip`, to give a list of data frames for each individual zip code. If you use `test.sample$zip` to subset this list, you will get a list of 50 data frames with the appropriate zip codes. You can then sample the fip using the weights in the `prob` column of each data frame.

In your case, that would look like this:

```r
sample_space <- split(index.dat, index.dat$zip)[test.sample$zip]

test.sample$fips <- sapply(sample_space, 
                           function(x) sample(x$fips, 1, prob = x$prob))
```

Now `test.sample$fips` will have a random fip chosen from the appropriate zip code, with the sampling done according to the relative weight. If we do a table of `test.sampl$fips`, we can see that the proportions are about right:

```r
table(test.sample$fips)

#> A1 A2  B C1 C2 
#> 13  5 19 10  3
```

The 18 members of zip 1 have been assigned to A1 and A2 with an (almost) 75:25 split. All members of zip 2 are given a B, as expected, and the 13 members of zip 3 have been assigned appropriately (though by chance no C3s have been selected due to its low probability)

If `test.sample` had 5000 rows, we would see that the proportions are much closer to the expected weightings due to the law of large numbers:

```r
#>   A1   A2    B   C1   C2   C3 
#> 1257  419 1687 1153  325  159
```

Comment: How would this scale? My sample space is billions and there are >40k zip codes. I used an lapply above which might parallelize easier I think but still not great.

Comment: @SCDCE it scales linearly - it should be O(n) complexity. The problem that will dog any solution here is memory usage. As long as you are able to do and store the equivalent of `split(index.dat, index.dat$zip)` to give your reference list of 40,000 zip codes and associated fips with weightings, then you can do your sampling a chunk at a time.

Comment: I'll give it a try, thanks for your time!