# Determine whether coordinates fall within geographic region

Tags: r, maps

I'm attempting to discern whether a given lat/long coordinate falls within a particular US state. I have used the `maps` package to obtain lat/long coordinates for state borders. I suspect there is a way to ask whether the coordinate falls within the range of lat and long values encompassed by each state, but I have not figured out an elegant solution.

Basically, this is a way to identify whether a point falls within a region without having to know the region's name (since the `maps` package is pretty idiosyncratic in terms of naming regions, e.g., USSR), but still having the ability to extract the region name at a later point (for shading, etc.).

```
#Example coordinates
points=data.frame(lat=42,long=-100)
#Load US map
library(maps)
states=map_data("state")
#Summarize value of lat and long values for each region
library(plyr)
ddply(states,c("region"),function(x) return(c( range(x$long), range(x$lat) )) )
```

In the end, I want the `data.frame` `states` to have a final column giving `true/false` as to whether the points occur in that region. So, in the above example, all entries where `region=="nebraska"` would have `true`.

Comment: [Here's a link to my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751497/latitude-longitude-coordinates-to-state-code-in-r/8751965#8751965) to a very similar question.

Comment: Indeed, that helped a lot. Sorry for opening a duplicate topic, but I can't appear to delete it. Voted to close