# Is there a function that returns the zipcode

Tags: r

Is there a function that returns the zipcode (or closest zipcode) for a given longitude and latitude.. It needs to scale because I have a long list of latitude by longitude

Comment: Look into Google maps geo coding api

Comment: Possibly interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751497/latitude-longitude-coordinates-to-state-code-in-r

Comment: Read the [R documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zipcode/zipcode.pdf) for the zipcode package.  Going from zipcode to latitude/longitude is easy, but the other way around will take a bit of effort on your part.

Answer (score 0):

A.1) You can download tables that contain the approximate coordinates of Zip Codes. For small zip codes area, it can be precise, but for large area in less populated zones, the coordinates would just be the middle point.

Maybe look at some search results: http://zips.sourceforge.net/

A.2) Then you can join your list of zip codes to get the coordinates.

B) You can try to use [geocode](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/ggmap/docs/geocode) from ggmap package

Further readings: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28035/how-to-convert-zip-codes-to-latitude-and-longitude

Answer (score 0):

Actually I was looking for a subroutine in R. I tried zipcode package but it didn't work too well..
I basically have a long list in longitudes and latitudes and need corresponding (or nearest) zip codes