# Go from map_data to SpatialPolygonsDataFrame

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sp

I want to make a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` using the output from get_map in ggplot2. I found a way to do it after some trial and error but it seems convoluted to me. Is there a cleaner way?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(sp)
library(plyr)
pnw.df <- map_data("state",region=c("washington","oregon","idaho"))
# delete islands from subregions
pnw.df$subregion[is.na(pnw.df$subregion)] <- "main" 
pnw.df <- subset(pnw.df,subregion == "main") 

getPolygons <- function(x) {
  Polygons(list(Polygon(x[,c("long","lat")])),ID=unique(x$region))
}

pnw.sp <- SpatialPolygons(dlply(pnw.df, .(region), getPolygons))
pnw.sp <- as(pnw.sp,"SpatialPolygonsDataFrame")
proj4string(pnw.sp) <- "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84"
plot(pnw.sp)
```

Comment: `ggplot2::map_data("state")` calls `maps::map("state", ...)` under the hood. Have a look at Josh O'Brien's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751497/latitude-longitude-coordinates-to-state-code-in-r/8751965#8751965) for a very convenient way to convert its output to 'SpatialPolygons'.

Answer (score 0):

Look into `maptools::map2SpatialPolygons`, an try its examples. `map_data` reads the data from `maps` and puts them in a `data.frame`, which is not very helpful. The maptools function takes the same data from `maps`, and converts them into a `SpatialPolygons` object.

Comment: Unfortunately `map2SpatialPolygons` is buggy @EdzerPebesma. `World2 <- map(database = "mapdata::world2Hires"); World2sp <- map2SpatialPolygons(World2, IDs = sub(":.*", "", World2$names), proj4string=CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))` gives an error: `map and IDs differ in length`. There are, indeed, only 2284 IDs versus 3905 elements in the list returned by this code: `xyList <- .NAmat2xyList(cbind(map$x, map$y))`.

Comment: I asked you to look at the examples: you need to add arguments `fill=TRUE` and `plot=FALSE`.

Comment: Thank you @EdzerPebesma! I was looking at the examples but somehow I completely missed `fill=TRUE`. That makes all the difference!